# How to log into another user if the entered password is wrong?

Tags: pam, pam-environment

How tp configure PAM in order to log as a special user (call it `wrongpass-user`) if a wrong password is entered for any other user?

Comment: Why on earth...?

Comment: Don't even consider doing that, that's a recipe for please anyone can gain access here!

Comment: I guess I'll use `pam_exec.so` with an empty password user and start a new GUI with xinit.